# How to keep title attribute from html link in jqGrid?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid, hyperlink, html-table

I have a column with the following values:

```
<td>            
    <a href="/carronovo6/adminp/noticias-crud/edit/id/1" class="rpl lk-editar tt" title="editar">Editar</a>
    <a href="/carronovo6/adminp/noticias-crud/delete/id/1" class="rpl lk-excluir tt" title="excluir">Excluir</a>
</td>
```

I am rendering  jqGrid tableToGrid in this way:

```
tableToGrid('#list', {
    datatype: 'local',
    rowNum: 10,
    pager: '#listpager',
    cmTemplate: { title: false },
    height: 'auto',
    width: 'auto',
    pgtext : "<span>Pág.</span> {0} <span>de</span> {1}"

});
```

I don't want to show tooltips in grid.

The attribute "title" from link disappears when I render jqGrid. 
How can I keep the attribute "title" in link?

Comment: If you don't want to show tooltips you don't need the titles...

Comment: @LajosArpad I am generating tooltips externally with jquery tooltip. It's strange the plugin remove the attribute. It must there be an option to keep it

Comment: If you find any events after these titles disappear you can set the title attribute of those tags.

Answer (score 0):

Change

cmTemplate: { title: false },

to

cmTemplate: { title: true },